# How to manipulate Java List with jsf RequestScope

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I'm using JSF 2.2 with RequestScoped managebean. I'd like to update a Java List inside of Customers entity. When submitting, only info in Java List (List<'Phone >) is gone. I don't want to use SessionScoped. Could anyone share some tips or solve this issue?

My codes are shown here.

Customers Entity:

```
{ ..
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;


    ...

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "CUSTOMERS_Phone",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMERS_ID"))
    @AttributeOverride(name = "teleNumbers",
            column = @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER",length=30))
    private List<Phone> phone;
..}
```

JSF Managebean:

```
    @Named(value = "editCustomersBeanService")
    @RequestScoped
    public class EditCustomersBeanService implements Serializable {

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of EditCustomersBeanService
         */
        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            customers =new Customers();
            phones = new ArrayList<>();
            customers.setPhone(phones);

        }

        public EditCustomersBeanService() {


        }


        @Inject
        private BusinessSessionCustomers businessSSCustomers;
        private int customerId;
        private List<Phone> phones;
        private Customers customers;

        //setter, getter ...

        //update to DB
        public String updatedCustomers() {
        System.out.println("customer Name: " + customers.getFirstname());
        System.out.println("customer LastName: " + customers.getLastname());
        System.out.print("List of Phones in updatedCustomers: ");
        for (Phone ph : customers.getPhone()) {
        System.out.print(ph.getPhoneType() + ", " + ph.getTeleNumbers());
        }

         businessSSCustomers.mergeToDB(customers);
         return "customers";
        }
    ..

}
```

CustomersEdit.xhtml:

```
<h:form>

    ...
    <label  for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
       <h:inputText  id="lastName"  p:placeholder="Last Name"
    value="#{editCustomersBeanService.customers.lastname}"/>

    <ui:repeat var="phone" value="#{editCustomersBeanService.customers.phone}"   varStatus="status">
    <label  for="phones">Phone: [#{status.index}]</label>

        <h:selectOneMenu     value="#{phone.phoneType}">
                       <f:selectItems  value="#{editCustomersBeanService.phoneTypeList}"
                             itemLabel="#{editCustomersBeanService.phoneType}" 
                             itemValue="#{editCustomersBeanService.phoneType}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
       <h:inputText class=" form-control" value="#{phone.teleNumbers}" />
     </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandLink  value="Save"   action="#{editCustomersBeanService.updatedCustomers()}"  />

    …
    </h:form>
```

Phone.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class Phone {

    public enum PhoneType {

        Home, Mobile, Work
    }
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE", length = 10)
    private PhoneType phoneType;
    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUM", length = 30)
    private String teleNumbers;
//setter, getter 
..
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. When submitting JSF form, the info form from List<Phone> can't be recorded. Other fields such as firstname, lastname can be recorded to DB. Note: I use stateless on EJB; also set to EAGER or LAZY type, but no difference.

Comment: Just explore/debug/print the `List<Phone>` inside `updatedCustomers()` before `mergeToDB()` is called? This way you can exclude JSF from being the cause and move the focus to JPA.

Comment: I got NullPointerException with printing. Then I modified codes with instantiating the List<Phone> (shown above). I tried to load a phone number and type to List<Phone>. It appeared correctly in JSF form. After that I updated, all info of List<Phone>, it's gone(printed nothing), but it could print firstName, lastName fields.

Comment: Now I use ViewScoped(javax.faces.view.ViewScoped) instead; there's no issue. So I could not success with RequestScoped when manipulating data for Collection type such as List.